# debug wpf by using sos.dll issue

Tags: wpf, debugging, memory-leaks, sos

I am using sos.dll to find memory leak in wpf .
And I found a wpf object was not released,
then I tried to find out why it is not released by using **!gcroot**

it gave me a warming that:

**Please note that 6c369950 is not a valid object.**

snippet of the debugging info

```
!dumpheap -type WPFUILib.MenuWindow
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
0c12ef4c       14          224 WPFUILib.MenuWindow+<>c__DisplayClass2b
03fdf624        2          816 WPFUILib.MenuWindow
Total 16 objects

!gcroot 03fdf624
Note: Roots found on stacks may be false positives. Run "!help gcroot" for
more info.
Please note that 03fdf624 is not a valid object.
```

Comment: I *think* it's because the object HAVE been released.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to find the roots for a MethodTable (MT), but `!gcroot` expects an object address. If you want to find the roots for your two instances of `WPFUILib.MenuWindow` you need to locate their addresses first. Use `!dumpheap -mt 03fdf624` to list the addresses and then use `!gcroot` on those.